# I am trying to disable my login button if the task is scuccefull

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to kotlin,
sorry in advance if my formatting is shit

following a tutorial  but when I use the

```
btn_register_rg.isEnabled = false
    btn_register_rg.alpha = 0.5f
```

### button in my XML :

```
    android:id="@+id/btn_login_log"
```

codes it shows me that unresolved reference although am using it my other functions like (in the same fragment)

```
view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_login_log).setOnClickListener(){
            validateForm()
```

that works just fine, but in this, it shows unresolved references and is colored red although the tutorial am following doesn't face this issue

```
 private fun firebaseSignIn(){
 //------>  btn_login_log.isEnabled = false
 //------>  btn_login_log.alpha = 0.5f
            fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username.text.toString(),
                password.text.toString()).addOnCompleteListener(){
                task ->
                if(task.isSuccessful){
    
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Login Succesful ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    
                    var navHome = activity as FragmentNavigation
                    navHome.navigateFragment(HomeFragment(),addTostack = true)
    
                }
                else{
 //------>          btn_login_log.isEnabled = false
//------>           btn_login_log.alpha = 1.5f
                    Toast.makeText(context, task.exception?.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you define val btn_login_log = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_login_log)

Answer (score 0):

When task is successful try to put below lines for disable button
`btn_login_log.isEnabled = false`
`btn_login_log.isClickable = false`

Comment: dont know how to attatch an image but it leads to the same issue